# LLVM : generating a "ir" file for specifically z80 processor using llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-gcc, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am working on LLVM, and want to generate the files according to specific target architecure e.g-z80. I have downloaded z80 source code and clang. I used --target in clang command to specify z80 but it is not working. can anybody help me out in this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

LLVM has no official z80 backend/target. There appear to be some third-party projects attempting to implement one, like [llvm-z80](https://github.com/earl1k/llvm-z80), so you can try to check them out. The alternative would be [writing a new backend](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html).